# Error running 'typeorm migration:run'. My 'extensions methods' are not recognized

Tags: node.js, typescript, typeorm, extension-methods

When I try to run the migration via typeORM, I get the following error:

> error TS2339: Property 'toMoney' does not exist on type 'number'.
> [image]

> The 'toMoney' method was an 'extension method' I created and it works normally.

```
export { };
declare global {
  export interface Number {
    round(this: number, decimalPlaces: number): number;
    toMoney(this: number): number;
    toPercentage(this: number, decimalPlaces: number): number;
  }
}

Number.prototype.toMoney = function (this: number): number {

  if (!this)
    return 0;

  return this.round(2);
};
```

This is my script in '**package.json**' to run the migration:

```
"typeorm": "ts-node --project ./tsconfig.json -r tsconfig-paths/register ./node_modules/typeorm/cli.js"
```

> npm run typeorm

Is there any way to load the 'extensions methods' while running typeORM ?