# Is there any way to pre-load external files/modules before generating/running typeorm migrations?

Tags: node.js, typescript, nestjs, typeorm, extension-methods

I have created a few extensions on some base classes, such as `Array` to add some functionality that is commonly used throughout our NestJS app.
Consider the following example:

We have a declaration in a .d file:

```
// in src/declarations/array.d.ts

declare interface Array<T> {
  undupe(key?: (e: T) => any): Array<T>; // method that removes duplicate elements from the array
}
```

And the corresponding implementation:

```
// src/implementations/array.implementation.ts

Array.prototype.undupe = function (
  this: Array<any>,
  key?: (e: any) => any,
): Array<any> {
  ...
};
```

In order for this to work, I am also importing `src/implementations/array.implementation.ts` in our `main.ts` file.

I am now trying to create a new entity that is importing a file that is using .undupe() somewhere in it an I am getting this error while generating a new migration for it using the typeorm CLI:

```
$ yarn typeorm migration:generate -n 'SomeMigration'
yarn run v1.22.19
warning ../../package.json: No license field
$ node --require ts-node/register ./node_modules/typeorm/cli.js migration:generate -n 'SomeMigration'
Error during migration generation:
<some-file-path-that-is-imported-in-the-new-entity-file> - error TS2339: Property 'undupe' does not exist on type 'number[]'.

292         .undupe();
             ~~~~~~

error Command failed with exit code 1.
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run for documentation about this command.
```

I tried specifically importing `src/implementations/array.implementation` in the file that is being imported, but that did not work.

I saw a similar error while using Jest, but I could easily solve that by specifying `src/implementations/array.implementation.ts` in the `setupFilesAfterEnv` field of our jest config json, like this:

```
{
...
"setupFilesAfterEnv": ["<rootDir>/src/implementations/array.implementation.ts"]
...
}
```

Is there something similar for TypeOrm? Or does anyone know another workaround to this?

Similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72512365/error-running-typeorm-migrationrun-my-extensions-methods-are-not-recognize) I found (with no answers)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some messing around, I found a way to fix this.
The issue wasn't with TypeORM, but with node (or ts-node) not including the declaration files, and the compiler complaining that the `undupe` property does not exist on `Array`.

Previously, I had in my `package.json`, the following line:

`"typeorm": "node --require ts-node/register ./node_modules/typeorm/cli.js"`

I changed this to use ts-node instead:

`"typeorm": "ts-node ./node_modules/typeorm/cli.js"`

I then had to edit my existing `tsconfig.json` file to add these lines:

```
// tsconfig.json
{
  "ts-node": {
    "files": true
  }, 
  "include": ["src/declarations/*"], 
  ... //rest of my ts-config below
}
```

Alternatively, I also found that this works as well:

```
// tsconfig.json
{
  "ts-node": {
    "files": true
  }, 
  "files": ["src/declarations/array.d.ts"], 
  ... //rest of my ts-config below
}
```

Source for the above can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62878548/14167792).